# Problem running my sql trigger code: ORA-24344: Success with Compilation Error

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I'm trying to create a trigger which updates a value `VALOR_RESTANTE` on `PRESTAMO` each time there's an insert on `PAGO`. As you can see in te code below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pago_a_prest
AFTER INSERT ON PAGO
FOR EACH ROW WHEN ( new.CODIGO_PREST IS NOT NULL )
DECLARE
current_year NUMBER(4);
current_mounth NUMBER(2);
current_date NUMBER(2);
BEGIN
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY')) FROM DUAL INTO current_year;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM')) FROM DUAL INTO current_mounth;
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD')) FROM DUAL INTO current_day;
UPDATE PRESTAMO SET VALOR_RESTANTE=VALOR_RESTANTE+(VALOR_TOTAL*TASA_INTERES/100)*(current_year-(SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(FECHA_INICIAL,'YYYY')) FROM PRESTAMO));
UPDATE PRESTAMO SET VALOR_RESTANTE=VALOR_RESTANTE-:NEW.VALOR_PAGO WHERE CODIGO_PREST = :NEW.CODIGO_PREST;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
ROLLBACK;
END pago_a_prest;
```

Once I run it, I get this error:

```
ORA-06512: en "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", línea 581
ORA-06512: en "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", línea 1658
ORA-06512: en "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100", línea 567
ORA-06512: en "APEX_200100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", línea 2127
```

I already verified all column names and the code for dates and don't know what should I do.

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing which lines are being referenced, the one thing that jumps out at me is that the syntax is `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM` not `SELECT ... FROM ... INTO`.  You also don't need to do a `SELECT` here.  Just `current_year := to_number( to_char( sysdate, 'YYYY' ) );'.

Comment: Thank you! The error was just right there, also the variable current_date was asigned with a diferent name.

Comment: You can run `show errors` to see the actual errors (that are implicated by "with compilation errors" )

Comment: [`current_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CURRENT_DATE.html) is a built-in function.

Comment: There are a couple other items that need addressing. Just a *caution*, your 1st update does not have a WHERE clause therefore it will update every row in the table. *Critical error*, your exception clause. A trigger cannot issue ROLLBACK, it will issue an ORA-04092; you should delete the entire section Finally just note setting  current_year can be assigned as "current_year := extract(year from sysdate); See [Extract Function](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-date-functions/oracle-extract/).

Answer (score 0):

- Get rid of all those local variables. You just need the value for `current_year` for which an extra SQL Statement is not needed.
- There are two Update Statements those should be combined( *I just showed a sample, but you need perform this should be rearranged due to your own or company's rules*  ), and the combined one needs a *Where* Clause to restrict the data to be updated.
- It's beneficient to apply `NVL(..,0)` function to each monetary value
  in order to avoid the miscalculations for the *null* values. Moreover, Rounding with a scale of 2 needed for those monetary values after multiplication and division operations.
- No subquery such as `(SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(FECHA_INICIAL,'YYYY')) FROM PRESTAMO)` needed. Since the column `FECHA_INICIAL`'s value is
  already been selected from the concerned table(`PRESTAMO`) which is
  the one being updated.

Therefore, you can rewrite the trigger as

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pago_a_prest
     AFTER INSERT ON PAGO
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN (NEW.CODIGO_PREST IS NOT NULL)       
   BEGIN
     UPDATE PRESTAMO
        SET VALOR_RESTANTE = NVL( VALOR_RESTANTE, 0)  - NVL( :NEW.VALOR_PAGO, 0) +
                             ROUND(
                                   ( NVL( VALOR_TOTAL, 0) * NVL( TASA_INTERES, 0) / 100) *
                                   ( TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') ) 
                                   - TO_NUMBER( TO_CHAR(FECHA_INICIAL, 'YYYY') ) )
                            ,2)                             
      WHERE CODIGO_PREST = :NEW.CODIGO_PREST;
   EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       ROLLBACK;
   END;
```